# How to find the result angle of a circle (segment?)

Tags: circles, angle

I would like to know how to calculate the angle of the 2 red lines based on screenshot below.

I have a circle and draw two lines of 45 degrees (black lines forming 90 degree angle). The red lines are the result of the 2 rectangles drawn on the circle.
I would like to calculate the angle of the 2 red lines.

We don't know anything else except the length and angle as seen in the screenshot.

**needed angle:**
[image]

I don't know if I am on the right forum. If not please let me know, I will delete the question and go to the forum I supposed to ask this question on.

Comment: qYour picture is confusing at it is very much not to scale and you use both m and M, presumably both for meter.  (The "rectangle" on the left is a completely different shape from the "rectangle" on the right.) Is the "rectangle" actually supposed to be a square? That is, is the $L=0.5m$ labelling the entire upper side? And is $L=0.5M$ the same length on the side? Is there a right angle where the extended radius of the circle meets the upper side of the rectangle?

Comment: At any rate, making the assumptions I asked about, I arrive at the conclusion that the picture is totally not to scale and that the first red radius makes an angle of 60º with the 45º radius. That is, the picture is totally wrong with the given measurements.

Comment: @TedShifrin the picture is made in paint since I dont have any other tool to draw with
The scale is not imprtant at all since dimensions are givin
The m and M are indeed meters and was a typo.

The diameter of circle is 2 meter 
the 2 "rectangles are same size. the 0.5m is 1 half so the total lenght of the upper side is 1.0 the "height" is indeed 0.5M

Comment: "The red lines are the result of the 2 rectangles drawn on the circle."  How do you draw a rectangle "on" a circle?  Your answer will depend on how we interpret that.

Answer (score 1):

With the correct dimensions, following vectors will answer the question. If we go a distance $\delta$ along the $45^\circ$ line from the circle to the far edge of the rectangle, then we find the upper intersection $P$ of the rectangle with the circle by solving for the value of $\delta$ to make the vector
\begin{align*}
(1+\delta)\big(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\big) + \frac12\big({-}\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac1{\sqrt2}\big) + \frac12\big({-}\frac1{\sqrt2},{-}\frac1{\sqrt2}\big)&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\big(1+\delta-1,1+\delta\big)\\ &= \frac1{\sqrt2}(1+\delta,\delta)
\end{align*}
lie on the circle. So its length must be $1$. This gives us the equation
$$(1+\delta)^2+\delta^2 = 2,$$
so, by the quadratic formula, $\delta = \dfrac{\sqrt3-1}2$. That tells us that the point $P$ is $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\big(\dfrac{\sqrt3+1}2,\dfrac{\sqrt3-1}2\big)$.

We can use dot product to find the angle $\theta$ between the vector $\overrightarrow{OP}$ and the $45^\circ$ line:
$$\cos\theta = \frac{(1,1)}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{(\sqrt3+1,\sqrt3-1)}{2\sqrt2} = \frac{\sqrt3}2.$$
This means that $\theta = 30^\circ$. This means that *half* your red angle is $(90-30-45)^\circ = 15^\circ$ and the whole red angle is $30^\circ$. Quite amazing how that worked out!!

**EDIT**: I followed the vectorial approach because that's how I worked the problem with my original understanding of the dimensions. However, having arrived at the answer, I now realize there's an easy solution using just basic geometry. As pictured, below, we have rectangle $PQRS$ with $PS=QR=1$. Let $O$ be the center of the unit circle. Therefore, $\triangle OPS$ is equilateral (since the circle has radius $1$). Bisecting $\angle SOP$ gives the $30^\circ$ angle between the radius perpendicular to $\overline{QR}$ and $\overline{OP}$, as required.

[image]

Comment: @ Ted Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Comment: You’re welcome. When you are satisfied that you have no further questions on it, please accept the answer!